# Need help to aggregate/count a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as such:

```
214111  12-JUN-13 06:17:11  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  57  0   57  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:17:35  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  55  0   55  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:19:14  MOVING  SPEED   143249  71  0   71  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:21:14  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  70  65  5   1
214111  12-JUN-13 06:23:14  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  70  0   70  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:32:10  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  40  0   40  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:55:35  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  63  55  8   1
214111  12-JUN-13 06:56:22  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  60  55  5   1
214111  12-JUN-13 07:02:43  MOVING  PRIOD   143307  27  0   27  0
214111  12-JUN-13 07:04:15  MOVING  PRIOD   143307  32  0   32  1
214111  12-JUN-13 07:04:25  MOVING  PRIOD   143307  22  0   22  1
214111  12-JUN-13 07:08:45  MOVING  PRIOD   143307  34  0   34  1
```

i would like to count the number of 1 in consecutive rows. counter will get reset when
0 occurs.

```
214111  12-JUN-13 06:17:11  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  57  0   57  0  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:17:35  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  55  0   55  0  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:19:14  MOVING  SPEED   143249  71  0   71  0  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:21:14  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  70  65  5   1  1
214111  12-JUN-13 06:23:14  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  70  0   70  0  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:32:10  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  40  0   40  0  0
214111  12-JUN-13 06:55:35  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  63  55  8   1  1
214111  12-JUN-13 06:56:22  MOVING  PRIOD   143249  60  55  5   1  2
214111  12-JUN-13 07:02:43  MOVING  PRIOD   143307  27  0   27  0  0
214111  12-JUN-13 07:04:15  MOVING  PRIOD   143307  32  0   32  1  1
214111  12-JUN-13 07:04:25  MOVING  PRIOD   143307  22  0   22  1  2
214111  12-JUN-13 07:08:45  MOVING  PRIOD   143307  34  0   34  1  3
```

need help...

Comment: Could you add the names of the columns in the first list? This can be done in Oracle but the answer won't make any sense if I make up a name for ten columns.

Comment: you want the biggest number of consecutive 0's? Or all the numbers of consecutive 0's ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little tricky.  Identify where the sequences start by using `lag()` -- a 1 following a 0 (or NULL).  Then do a cumulative sum of those values.  The cumulative sum identifies a sequence starting with 1s followed by 0s.  Then do a cumulative sum and some logic to get the final value:

```
select t.*,
       (case when val = 0 then 0
             else SUM(ind) over (partition by grp order by dt)
        end) as counter
from (select t.*, SUM(ind) over (order by dt) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when val = 1 and lag(val) over (order by dt) = 0 then 1 else 0
                    end) as ind
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon let me try this..

Comment: Gordon i am new in lead and lag function. can you explain bit more what is dt in your the query when you are saying "order by dt"